# Let $f$ be a real valued function with the rule $f(x)= x^3 +3x^2 + 6x + 14$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials

Let $f$ be a real valued function with the rule $f(x) = x^3 +3x^2 + 6x + 14$ defined for all real value of $x$.

It is given that $a$ and $b$ are two real numbers such that $f(a)= 1$ and $f(b)= 19$, find the value of $(a+b)^2$.

I tried to approach this question by writing to equations for $f(a) = 1$ and $f(b) = 19$ and tried to add these equations to get the value of $(a+b)^2$, but ended up getting the answer in terms of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  In order for MathJax commands to be effective, they must be enclosed in`$` signs.  For example, `$x^2$` shows up as $x^2$.

Comment: Ok I will try to do it next time thanks

Comment: @AnubhavKumar What's the context, and is there a reason to expect a "nicer" solution than brute force?

Comment: I get $a+b = -2$ so $(a+b)^2 = 4$.  I used Cardano, but there should be a clever method that is simpler.

Comment: @dxiv I know by a matter of fact that the answer is a non negative integer between 0 and 99 and thus it can't have variables

Comment: @AnubhavKumar You can brute force it using resultants, see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=resultant%28x%5E3%2B3x%5E2%2B6x%2B14-1%2C+%28y-x%29%5E3%2B3%28y-x%29%5E2%2B6%28y-x%29%2B14-19%2C+x%29) for example. Question was whether you had any reason to expect a "nice" solution, instead.

Comment: Could be done by elimination, as well.  Using the three polynomial equations $\{u = (a+b)^2,f(a)=1,f(b)=19\}$ eliminate $a$ and $b$.  Factor the resulting polynomial for $u$, and show all zeros other than $u=4$ are non-real.

Comment: @GEdgar   seems to come from $(x+1)^2 + 3 (x+1) + 10$ being set to $1$    and $19,$   just symmetry. I will fiddle with it some more... Yes, $(a+1)^2 + 3 (a+1) = -9$   and $(b+1)^2 + 3 (b+1) = 9,$   rotational symmetry  around $(-1,0)$

Comment: @WillJagy That's it.  With $u=a+1$, $v=b+1$ we have $u^3+3u+9=0$, and $v^3+3v-9=0$, so $u=-v$.